# How do I query this case?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables.

```
Category(id, name);
Item(id, name, category);
SoldItem(id, item, qty);
```

My goal is simple, I want to list ALL the categories plus item count of those categories plus the count of sold items of the items of those particular categories as rows.

The result would be like this:

```
Category | Item count | Item sold count
----------------------------------------
Food     | 2          | 50
----------------------------------------
Beverage | 3          | 60
```

How do I query this in PostgreSQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use `count(distinct)` when counting rows from the middle joined table, otherwise multiple grandchildren would result in the same patent being counted multiple times too:

```
select
    c.name as category,
    count(distinct i.id) as item_count,
    sum(si.qty) as item_sold_count
from Category c
left join Item i on i.category = c.id
left join SoldItem si on si.item = i.id
group by c.name;
```

By using `left` joins, categories without items, and items with sales, will still show but with zeros for the totals.

Comment: the count(i.id) doesn't show the actual number as it's affected by the number of rows in the SoldItem that relate to that particular Item.

Comment: @William oops - I left out `distinct`. Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! You're so helpful as always.